# how to enable/draw grid lines for JointJS graph

Tags: jointjs

Does JointJs has an option to enable/draw grid lines for a graph?

If it doesn't, is there a way to customize the implementation and draw grid lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to draw grid lines in JointJS paper, taking advantage of the HTML 5 canvas element:

```
function setGrid(paper, gridSize, color) {
    // Set grid size on the JointJS paper object (joint.dia.Paper instance)
    paper.options.gridSize = gridSize;
    // Draw a grid into the HTML 5 canvas and convert it to a data URI image
    var canvas = $('<canvas/>', { width: gridSize, height: gridSize });
    canvas[0].width = gridSize;
    canvas[0].height = gridSize;
    var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(1, 1, 1, 1);
    context.fillStyle = color || '#AAAAAA';
    context.fill();
    // Finally, set the grid background image of the paper container element.
    var gridBackgroundImage = canvas[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    paper.$el.css('background-image', 'url("' + gridBackgroundImage + '")');
}

// Example usage:
setGrid(paper, 10, '#FF0000');
```

Comment: Thank you, I did a small change to 'context.rect()' call to draw a solid rectangle. Though having this as an option in JointJs itself seems to be helpful :)

Comment: We will definitely consider adding such an API right into the joint.dia.Paper object.

Answer (score 5):

According to [jointjs changelog](https://github.com/clientIO/joint/blob/master/CHANGELOG) you can now display grid via `drawGrid` option of `joint.dia.paper`.

Here's an example :

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
  el: $('#myholder-small'),
  width: 600,
  height: 100,
  model: graph,
  gridSize: 15,
  drawGrid:true
});
```

PS : [jointjs doc](http://jointjs.com/api) doesn't explicit this option.